# Imagemagick using properties to mass rename images

Tags: command-line, batch-file, rename, imagemagick, batch-rename

I have got a ton of dicom files that I want to mass rename using their properties tags.

My question is, what is the syntax for taking a property tag(such as dcm:SeriesNumber) for every image and using it to rename the images in the directory?

I'm guessing it involves breaking it down to the relevant tag using -identify -verbose and then somehow passing that string over to the filename property?

Really would appreciate the help(using win10 command line).

Comment: If you [edit] the question to show the relevant imagemagick output somebody might be able to help you with parsing and renaming.

Comment: Google "Exiftool" - you will find a free tool that in itself can do the task you ask for. It is available for major OS*es.

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069). You already asked [Imagemagick using metadata properties to mass rename images](//stackoverflow.com/q/40019895)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, since it doesn't address how you would modify your script using ImageMagicK.  But, I think this could save you, or someone else a ton of time using the best and easiest tools for a given problem.

I've done a fair amount of work with a bunch of files with property tags, and I've found that, unless you are trying to build a script to automate some process for a regularly occurring job, you'll be much better off using an application made specifically for this task:  ACDSee is a great commercial package, which doesn't have a free version that I know of: [www.acdsee.com/](http://www.acdsee.com/) and so is XNviewMP, which is completely free for personal use: http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/  Both can be installed without malware from the original companies.

With both tools, there are a lot of conversion tools included.  But, dealing with tags, renaming files, retagging files is in a different category that these tools excel in delivering.  Find and use the best tool with the lowest learning curve possible for this specific requirement.